# Setting page zoom to user preference

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I would like the users of my web app to be able to set the level of zoom they want for each page in my app, store that zoom level as a cookie (for each page), and zoom the page to the desired level the next time the user displays that page.

I have been able to do this with a popup window that has arrows on it, allowing the user to specify the amount of zoom and X and Y offset.  But, this is tedius for the user.  What I really want is to allow the user of a phone/tablet to specify the zoom they want simply with a pinch and/or spread action available on phones and tablets.

My problem is that I can't reliably detect the amount of zoom created by the user action of pinching and/or spreading.  I tried using

var zoom = window.outerWidth / window.innerWidth;

This works in Chrome, but doesn't change in Firefox when the user changes the zoom level.

Does anyone know how to reliable detect the zoom level after a pinching and/or spreading action performed by the user across all modern browsers?

Thanks,
Gary